# The Mystery of the Integrating Factor

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

The other day I was taught that to solve equations of the form

$$
f'+pf=q,
$$

where $f=f(t)$, $p=p(t)$ and $q=q(t)$, I need to use a function, or *integrating factor*, $\mu=\mu(t)$ such that

$$
\mu'=\mu p.
$$

However, how do I know that such function $\mu$ exists at all? In other words, can I **always** find $\mu$?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Subject to some assumptions, you can figure out what $\mu$ must look like. Consider that you have

$$\frac{d\mu}{d x} = \mu \cdot p(x)$$

Separating variables and integrating:

$$\int \frac{d\mu}{\mu} = \int p(x) dx$$

which implies that

$$\log \mu = \int p(x) dx$$

or

$$\mu(t) = \exp \left( \int_{t_0}^t p(x) dx \right)$$

So as long as $p(x)$ has a first integral, the function $\mu(x)$ exists.

Answer (score 1):

However you've got your answer, I'd like to note you some other points. The OE $$y'=f(t,y)$$ can be always written as $$M(t,y)dt+N(t,y)dy=0$$ For example your OE is as $\frac{dy}{dt}+py=q$ or $dy+[py-q]dt=0$. Here, we find $M=py-q$ and $N=1$. Now the following tool can help you. Please pay attention to the assumptions inside it:

> Theorem: If $\mu$ be a function of $z$ and $z$ is itself a function of $x$ and $y$,i.e.; $$\mu=\mu(z(x,y))$$ and if $\mu$ be an integrating factor of $$M(x,y)dx+N(x,y)dy=0$$ then; $$\mu=\exp\left(\int\frac{M_y-N_x}{z_xN-z_yM}dz\right)$$ provided the integrand is a function of $z$.

This theorem can lead us to find the proper function which makes a non-exact OE exact.

Comment: Mystery solved! +1